# resources not found after renaming folder (Eclipse, Maven)

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

My prior, working code:

Directory structure:

```
src/main/java/mypackage/MyClass
src/main/resources/mypackage/someFile.txt
```

In the code:

```
URI uri = MyClass.class.getResource("someFile.txt").toURI();
```

Now I changed it to this:

Directory structure:

```
src/main/java/de.abc.mypackage/MyClass
src/main/resources/de.abc.mypackage/someFile.txt
```

In the code:

```
URI uri = MyClass.class.getResource("someFile.txt").toURI();
```

or

```
URI uri = MyClass.class.getResource("de.abc.mypackage/someFile.txt").toURI();
```

In both cases, it doesn't find the file, I get a NullPointerException.

What do I need to change?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use path as src/main/resources/de/abc/mypackage/someFile.txt

Comment: but why did it work without the src/main/resources... before that?

Comment: perhaps you have problem with your classpath. I've build the same directory structure as you have and for me works  the code

Comment: got it... I added something to the path elsewhere in the code and that messed it up. Thanks though!